# iOS: sin() Symbols not found for architecture i386

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, linker

I'm trying to use sin(), cos(), tan() from math.h in an iPhone (simulator) app.

What do I need to change to get the standard C math library functions to link in?

I'm making calls from .cpp files.

e.g.

```
#include <math.h>
..
float f = tan( p1 );
```

Linker output:

```
  "tan(float)", referenced from:

      GetTan(float) in myfuncs.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I missing a needed framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some environments you need to explicitly link `libm` in order to get transcendental math functions, so try adding `-lm` to your linker flags.

Comment: Is this just a matter of adding "-lm" or "lm" to "Other Linker Flags"?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best way to do it in Xcode.

Comment: Excellent - cosf(), sinf() etc work well. This is cross-platform code so I'll throw in a #define macro to change the iOS versions to sinf() etc.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed this is C++. not C (the use of the C `<math.h>` header threw me off) - so just use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` and then you don't need to worry about the argument/return types - just use `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, etc. I've deleted that part of the answer now as it's not really relevant for C++.

Comment: You were OK - my code is a mixture of C and C++ - most files are .cpp with a few .c files here and there.